# Time out error running Selenium from Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm having trouble running SeleniumRC from Django.  I can run the sample code provided by the [Selenium docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#python) and the [python selenium client docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) just fine from in a Python shell without running Django (so no manage.py), but when I actually try to run Selenium from a django TestCase or from the Django shell, I get a timeout error. 
Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
from selenium import selenium
from django.test import TestCase

class TestSelenium(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_foo(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/")
```

Running with manage.py test registration.TestSelenium produces the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_testformmaintainsdata (registration.tests.TestSelenium)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/Documents/dev/app/CustomMade/registration/tests.py", line 158, in setUp
    self.selenium.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 189, in start
    result = self.get_string("getNewBrowserSession", start_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 223, in get_string
    result = self.do_command(verb, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 214, in do_command
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 990, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 391, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 349, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 427, in readline
    data = recv(1)
timeout: timed out

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 12.475s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database 'default'...
```

The strange thing is that even though the error is thrown, and Python stops, the SeleniumRC server does actually launch Firefox, but then I can't run further Selenium commands since Django has stopped.  This is the output from SeleniumServer:

```
14:21:48.362 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
14:21:48.369 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox, http://127.0.0.1:8000/, ] on session null
14:21:48.372 INFO - creating new remote session
14:21:48.443 INFO - Allocated session a3ea05a3d0eb4956ba69a67583ea49ba for http://127.0.0.1:8000/, launching...
14:21:48.533 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
14:21:51.473 INFO - Launching Firefox...
14:21:55.904 INFO - Got result: OK,a3ea05a3d0eb4956ba69a67583ea49ba on session a3ea05a3d0eb4956ba69a67583ea49ba
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has this problem, I was able to solve it by increasing my socket timeout in the setUp method.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick with the timeout value in float seconds:

```
import socket

from selenium import selenium
from django.test import TestCase

class TestSelenium(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        socket.settimeout(30)
        # ...
        self.selenium.start()
```

Refer to [python stdlib docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)